# Display error message if ID not Found in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

My employee(Customer) diary is based on CustomerID, [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwjHE.png).

If I am creating new Diary I need the CustomerID.

If I am using correct CustomerId that is present in database then it works properly, but if I am using an incorrect customerID then its showing the view to me and displaying error about other fields.

I just want to see the error message saying "ID not found"

Here is my create diary Code and image [@nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2caQy.png) I just want to see an error message if I am putting in wrong customerID
my Controller code for create Diary

// POST: /Diary/Create

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Diary diary)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            cd.Diaries.Add(diary);
            cd.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }

        return PartialView("_CreateDiary");
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding you correctly but why not just add in a condition that throws/displays an error?

Comment: actully i dont know how to apply that condition , can you just modify my code by usig that condition

Comment: You should be supplying the customerID to the `Create` action.  Looking at the image you shared, you're viewing a customer diary list, then adding a new diary..  So you should have the customer ID of the list, so pass that a long, store as hidden field, and eliminate the customer id textbox.. At the very least, it should use a dropdownlist to display foreign key fields..

Comment: @JamieD77 could you please tell me how to do that by modifying my code, because i don't know how to do that, please

Comment: You have not shown your model, or the view or the GET method so difficult to understand what your real issue is, but it seems related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411835/want-to-display-dropdown-list-in-customerid-field?noredirect=1#comment54613886_33411835)

Answer (score 1):

First add the condition to check based upon the entered `CustomerId` and add a model error if needed:

**Controller**

```
if (!cd.Customers.Any(c => c.Id == diary.CustomerId)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("CustomerId", "Customer not found");
}
```

Then add the following to your view (or a ValidationSummary)

**View**

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomerId")
```

I would advise displaying a list of customers that the user selects instead, this will improve the UI experience and also avoid errors like this.

**Full controller code**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Diary diary)
{

   if (!cd.Customers.Any(c => c.Id == diary.CustomerId)
   {
    ModelState.AddModelError("CustomerId", "Customer not found");
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        cd.Diaries.Add(diary);
        cd.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }

    return PartialView("_CreateDiary");
}
```

Comment: sorry where do i need to add this condition in conroller ? is it in the create action?

Comment: In the post create, I added the full controller code and the bit you need to add to the view. Please see above.

Comment: thank you ! yeah thats seems easy to display list of customers who are present in database , can you give me idea how to do that

Comment: @user5487417 No problem. I would add a list of customer objects in say a `AvailableCustomers` property. Populate them form your controller. Add a `SelectedCustomerId` with the selected property. Then bind with a dropdown list. Have a go and if you get stuck create a new question, someone will answer pretty quickly. Good luck. :)

Comment: this code is working and showing customer not found,but its having some problem , like its going back to view instead of giving me streight up error message,

Comment: it would be great if you just modify my code by using availableCustomer property. Thank you very much for your help. M very new to MVc don't kno much how to add this

Comment: sorry, if disturbing you, can you just tell me how to add customer object in property and how to populate them from controller

Comment: @user5487417 Hi, sorry unfortunately I am no longer at a pc, this is from my phone. I will pick it up when I get back on, it's def worth creating a new question as other's will help or answer. With the question changing it will put others off answering.

Comment: so my new question will be something like this , how to add a list of customer object in dropdown property ?? can you just tell me how to ask question realated this issue

Comment: could you please help me in this point adding dropdown list, pleass

Comment: @KiranJawandha Hi Sorry, I've not had time as of yet. It might be worth creating a new question, others will help probably quicker than me.